# Does every UI thread have its own dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In WPF, is it true that every dispatcher has its own thread? From the [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

> Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is
>   associated with.

we know that a dispatcher can only be associated at most one thread. Can two different threads share one dispatcher? If I understand correctly, Dispatcher is an abstraction controlling a message pump, i.e. an application can send messages to the Dispatcher, and it takes care of executing them on its thread. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There is a one to one relationship between a thread and a dispatcher. That said, multiple threads *can* queue work on the UI threads dispatcher (e.g In WPF you use `Application.Current.Disptacher`). You actually have to do that if you want to interact with UI elements from a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However you have to understand the fact That there can be and always is only one UI thread. And as there is a one to one relationship between the thread and the dispatcher, it means there is only one dispatcher for the (one) UI thread.

I.e. There can't be two threads associated with a single dispatcher, as there is only one UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> If a Dispatcher is not associated with the current thread, a new Dispatcher will be created. This is not the case with the FromThread method. FromThread will return null if there is not a dispatcher associated with the specified thread.

If you interpret that text a Thread owns (or is associated with) one dispatcher, and each association between the two are 1-1, since there is no setter for the Dispatcher in the Thread class.